# Call Javascript Function From iOS Webview in Angularjs App

Tags: javascript, objective-c, angularjs, cocoa

My problem is that when I try to call a javascript function that exists in my AngularJS app from within a UIWebView that function is not recognized. When I call the function in a typical html structure the function is recognized as expected. Example provided below:

OBJECTIVE-C:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // CODE GOES HERE
    _webView.delegate = self;

    // LOAD THE CHABACORP HOMEPAGE WITH INITIAL UIWEBVIEW
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://testing.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"testing()"];

}
```

ANGULARJS CONTROLLER:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testing.controllers', [])

.controller('Testing', function($scope) {

    function testing() {
        alert('testing');
    }

});
```

BASIC HTML (WORKS WITH CURRENT OBJECTIVE-C):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>

    <SCRIPT>
    function testing() {
        alert('testing');
    }
    </SCRIPT>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to read up on and understand [scope in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your `testing` function isn't globally available. It's only available inside your `Testing` controller function. To make it globally available, you need to modify the controller to be something like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testing.controllers', [])

.controller('Testing', function($scope) {

    window.testing = function() {
        alert('testing');
    }

});
```

Can't say that I recommend you to do this though, but it's hard to judge since we don't know more about why you want to do this.

Comment: I've developed an angular app, and I've wrapped it in a UIWebView in order to create a native iOS app. Basically I found no1 will use the app unless its native. So instead of just going completely native with the build I thought if there is a way to execute javascript functions from the WebView it would save me a lot of work.