# How to use angularjs/javascript and objective c together?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, angularjs

I want to use my existing angularjs functionality in my ios app.
I will be sending data from Obj C to angularjs, angular will check if the data is correct, and then send back a response "ok" to Obj C.

When Obj C receives the response "ok", it will load the second view controller.

For some reason it seems like

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

and

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

are not by my side.. 
I will have to go back and forth between Obj C and AngularJS.

Any help would be really appreciated. If you have code samples and links, please do post it.

Thanks

Comment: I am afraid that the `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` is the only way i know with which u can call obj-c from javascript. What is the reason for not being able to use this method?

Comment: After passing the parameters through `webViewDidFinishLoad`,even the sample alert in my js is not getting fired

Comment: I am not sure but i am assuming that u are trying to run js code with `- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script` in `webViewDidFinishLoad`?

Comment: Yes.. I am calling my js function there and passing the parameters

Comment: Then i believe simple js like `webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('ok')"]` should work. The problem could be that ur function is not in the window's scope. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407062/call-javascript-function-from-ios-webview-in-angularjs-app) may have a little help